# How can a non-conservative field be a scalar multiple of a conservative field?

Tags: conservation-laws, electric-fields, vector-fields, inductance

Okay so I was reading this from University Physics by Freeman and Young and on the topic of inductors as  circuit element, they wrote that $\mathbf{E_c} + \mathbf{E_n} = 0$ which makes no sense to me

Here is an excerpt of the text and underlined the confusion with green

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relationship $\vec E_c + \vec E_n = 0$ does not hold *globally* so the two fields are not scalar multiples.

Within, *and only within*, the (ideal) conductor that forms the inductor, the electric field must be zero.

Note that the text specifically says

> so the *total* electric field ... within the coils must be zero.

UPDATE:

Consider the general $E$ field in terms of the scalar and vector potentials:

$\vec E = -\nabla V - \dfrac{\partial\vec A}{\partial t}$

The first term, the gradient of the scalar potential, is conservative (curl of the gradient is identically zero) so any non-conservative component must come from the second term so let's identify:

$\vec E_c = -\nabla V$

$\vec E_n = - \dfrac{\partial\vec A}{\partial t}$

Now, if these fields are scalar multiples, $\vec E_n$ must be conservative which implies that $\vec B = 0$.

But, in your problem, $\vec B$ is non-zero and time-varying so $\vec E_n$ non-zero and is not conservative and so the two fields are not scalar multiples.

However, it is clearly possible to impose the constraint $\vec E_c + \vec E_n = 0$ *somewhere* but not *everywhere*.

Consider the following two electric fields:

$\vec E_c = K \hat x$

$\vec E_n = -y \hat x$

Clearly, $\vec E_c$ is conservative and $\vec E_n$ is non-conservative.

However, it is also clear that $\vec E_c + \vec E_n = 0$ when $y = K$

And, there you have it, a simple example of a conservative field being cancelled somewhere but not everywhere by a non-conservative field.

Comment: No, but even inside the inductor, how could this happen? I am confused as why that relationship should hold *anywhere*

Comment: @jak, how could *what* happen?  What does "this" refer to?  That a conservative field and a non-conservative field can exactly cancel within a limited region?

Comment: $\vec{E_c} + \vec{E_n} = 0 \implies \vec{E_c} = -\vec{E_n}$. How can multiplying a conservative field by -1 change the non-conservative behavior?

Comment: @jak, you're not, *not* multiplying a conservative *field* by -1 because the $\vec E_c$ and $\vec E_n$ are *not* proportional *everywhere*.  They are proportional *only within the conductor*. $\vec E_c$ and $\vec E_n$ are not proportional outside the conductor so you are not multiplying the *field* by $-1$.

Comment: "They are proportional only within the conductor", so inside the conductor one is the multiple of another?

Comment: @jak You would certainly expect non-scalar multiples to be equal *somewhere*. Being equal everywhere is very different.

Comment: Not if they are linearly independent actually

Comment: @jak, see update to my answer

Answer (score -1):

A field is conservative in an unbounded domain if its divergence is nul. In a bounded domain it is no longer the case, there is a surface integral which is non zero even if the divergence is nul.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition